# Launcher activity open two times using deeplinking

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

Here is the thing :

I must implement deep linking with an end point that is the launcher activity of the application.

So in the manifest, in the launcher activity tag there is :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Snippet from the activity onCreate method :

```
        if (getIntent() != null) {
            // Url scheme
            if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
                // Process the deelink
            } else {
                // Do something else
            }
        }
```

Problem : The activity opens two times, one with the good intent (ACTION_VIEW) and one without

I tried using tags like single_top, single_task, single_instance but then only the bad intent is launched (the default launcher intent).

---

How can I make it so that the two intent filter are triggered one at a time ?

Comment: Can you post code of the activity where you actually parse deeplink?

Comment: It should be irrelevant since the activity must not be created two times... but i'll past part of the code form onCreate

Comment: You are right, sorry. Please see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have 2 `intent-filters`. I don't know if this is true, but, the way I handle deep links is next:

Create new activity

```
DeepLinkActivity.class
```

`OnCreate()` method, don't set content view, this activity will be only for parsing deeplink that you want to parse. From there, you create intents and pass data to next activity you want to open. Hope it helps in any way.

***Edit***

In your case, create new activity DeepLinkActivity, add him intent filters

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Now, don't set content view for that activity, parse deeplink you get from `getIntent()` method and continue to whatever activity you want, this won't trigger your start intent.

Comment: It won't solve the issue in my case. The launcher intent will still be triggered. What i'm trying to achieve is to not trigger the launcher intent when it is not needed (when there is a deeplink with action view intent)

Comment: I'm testing your solution. it seems to work. I created a new activity for managing the deeplink and then finish() it. But there is a graphic bug like a blink at the app start... Can't i use a broadcast receiver for that ? :/

Comment: hm, did you delete setContentView() in your deeplinking activity?

Comment: I did delete it